# Select2 on bootstrap modal disappears when click option?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-select2

[image]
[image]
Why select2 disappears when clicked on option results? it uses ajax source data, when search result is clicked the option select disappears.

- Select2 version : 4.0.5
- jQuery Version : jQuery v1.11.1

I use codeigniter and here's my code :

views

```
<!-- Modal Tambah -->
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modal_form" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
                <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
            <!--    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/> -->
                <div class="modal-body form">
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-3 col-sm-2 control-label">Tindakan Item</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9">

                                <select name="tindakan_item_id" id="tindakan_item_id" class="select_tindakan_id form-control" autofocus="autofocus"></select>
                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="layanan_pemeriksaan_id" value="<?php echo $layanan_id; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="layanan_tindakan_pasien_id" value="<?php echo $layanan_id; ?>">

                        <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END Modal Tambah -->
```

and here's the javascript code

```
$('.select_tindakan_id').select2({
    placeholder: '--- Silahkan Pilih ---',
    dropdownParent: $("#modal_form"),
    width: '100%',
    ajax: {
      url: '<?php echo site_url('perawatan/layanan_tindakan_pasien_/search_tindakan'); ?>',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 2
});
```

controller

```
public function search_tindakan()
{
    $json = [];

    $this->load->database();
    if(!empty($this->input->get("q"))){
        $this->db->like('nama', $this->input->get("q"));
        $query = $this->db->select('id,nama as text,tindakan_id')
                    ->limit(10)
                    ->get("tindakan_item");
        $json = $query->result();
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but I can't see any problem. Check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/82buut01/

Comment: any idea what's wrong? I use firefox browser, is it related with browser issue?

Comment: My fiddle works correctly also on Firefox 57... Maybe you can share more code to understand if there is something wrong. Do you checked my fiddle?

Comment: yes, I've check your fiddle.

Comment: I found an error because of this code on my js
<code>
$("select").change(function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
        $(this).next().empty();
    });
</code>

Problem Solved

Comment: facing same problem, random issue, sometimes works perfect sometimes after clicking it suddenly disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem today, after get the solution I just see your last feedback that has been solve by yourself. My solution is by add .not() selector for exclude select2 element from the function effect.

I am using

- Select2 version 4.0.11
- jQuery version 3.4.1
- Bootstrap version 4.3.1

Before

```
$("select").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
    $(this).next().empty();
});
```

After

```
$("select").not('.select2').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
    $(this).next().empty();
});
```

Hope can help other who search solution for similar problem.